# Hibernate mapping exception on RHEL 6.7 but the code works file on RHEL6.5

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, rhel7, rhel5

I have two packages which need to be scanned for hibernating mappings.

```
<property name="mappingLocations">
    <list>
        <value>classpath:com/a/b/c/**/*.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>classpath:com/a/b/d/**/*.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

This works fine on RHEL 6.5 but on RHEL 6.7 it throws a **MappingException**.

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table abc_table refers to an unmapped class: com.a.b.d.bean.Variable.

**The mapping of abc_table is present in com.a.b.c package and Mapping for the class com.a.b.d.bean.Variable is present.**
Are there any changes in red hat os regarding loading the hibernate mappings? 
Does it have to do anything with classpath?
 Please suggest an appropriate approach as I could not find one. 

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: I assume you're using the same JDK major version in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched more for resolving the classpath and found [this](https://blog.carbonfive.com/2007/05/17/using-classpath-vs-classpath-when-loading-spring-resources/). Changed the code as shown below and it worked.

```
<property name="mappingLocations">
<list>
    <value>classpath*:com/a/b/c/**/*.hbm.xml</value>
    <value>classpath:com/a/b/d/**/*.hbm.xml</value>
</list>
```

Thank you Naros for the reply!